# Yeoman sideloaded Outlook add-in not showing in shared folders, but does load if deployed through Office 365 admin portal

Tags: office-js

I am trying to debug / develop an Outlook add-in utilizing the shared folders.  I added the true tag to the manifest. However when sideloading using the "npm start" command, the add-in only shows up in mailboxes that aren't shared.

I also tried deploying the add-in using the Office 365 admin portal for the organization.  When doing this, the add-in does show up in the shared mailbox folders so I don't think there is an issue with the manifest file.  Of course it would be extremely difficult to debug / develop code if I have to deploy it with the associated day or two delay with the admin portal deployment and lack of debugger support.

Update: I'm not sure what changed as I had already tried rebooting my computer before posting this, but it's working for me now.  It must have just been an intermittent issue.  I'm not sure what to suggest to anyone else other than try a couple more reboots...

Comment: This could have been a one off issue, and for whatever reason the new add-in didn't come down from the Exchange Server to the Client. Usually rebooting will force it to update. You can always check what "version" of the app was downloaded (and currently in use) by checking the cache. %localappdata%/Microsoft/Office/16.0/wef/[GUID]/[ID]/[GUID]/Manifests (the value in brackets will vary per computer/account)